# Opposite of RESTRICT in MySQL Foreign Key On Delete?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm in the process of redesigning some application security log tables (things like when users log in, access different files, etc.) to address some changing requirements.  They were originally made with `MyISAM`, but don't really get accessed that often and switching to `InnoDB` and adding a bunch of foreign keys for data integrity would really be more beneficial. Since I have to remake the tables anyway, I figure this is as good a time as ever to make the switch.

For the most part, everything is straightforward foreign keys and works as expected. The only part that where I'm trying something weird and hitting problems is with user_ids. Each record in these log tables is associated with a user_id, and I want to make sure the given user_id exists when a record is inserted.  Adding a foreign key that references the user table solves that problem - simple stuff. Here are some concise, representative tables:

**The User Table**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Example Log Table**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_login_time (
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
  login_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT 'tbl_login_time_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES tbl_user
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE ???
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

My problem is that I want the foreign key enforced for inserts, updates to be cascaded, but deleting records in tbl_user to not affect tbl_login_time at all.  Normally users get marked as inactive, but every once in awhile a user gets deleted entirely yet the logs need to be maintained.

The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) lists 6 options for `ON DELETE`, and none of them sound appropriate:

1. **RESTRICT**: Would prevent the deletion in tbl_user.
2. **NO ACTION**: Gets evaluated just like RESTRICT.
3. **CASCADE**: Would delete in tbl_user like I want, but also in tbl_login_time.
4. **SET NULL**: Would delete in tbl_user, and leave the row in tbl_login_time but nulls out the data. Close but no cigar.
5. **SET DEFAULT**: MySQL recognizes it, but rejects it.
6. **Omit ON DELETE**: Equivalent to RESTRICT.

I've never used a foreign key like this before (enforce `INSERT` and `UPDATE` but not `DELETE`), and after reading a lot of other questions it doesn't seem like anyone else does either. That should probably tell me this is the wrong approach, but can it work somehow?

Comment: Are you able to use a trigger?

Comment: @njk I could add triggers to the user table if I need to, but normally I try to avoid them if possible. If it turns out you can't make this work with foreign keys and have to use triggers, that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Deleting user records while leaving log with IDs referencing doesn't seem to be very practical. Looks like a design flaw to me. Why don't you just use some deactivation flag/get rid of user-log dependecy, if you need to keep the logs?

Comment: @rosipov After working on it a bit and seeing the first two comments here I'm thinking it probably isn't the right way to do this.  Using triggers to ensure only valid data gets entered may be the way to go, but I'm still curious can you pull this off with foreign keys?

Comment: Foreign keys manage dependencies (A must depend on B), you are trying to ignore that fact (A must depend on B, except for when there is no B). I'll leave the technical side of using foreign keys this way to experts. But: I don't really like the idea of user ID without the user in logs table -- it becomes junk data as soon as the user gets deleted. Bottom line - you rarely want to entirely delete data in production app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that I want the foreign key enforced for inserts,
>   updates to be cascaded, but deleting records in tbl_user to not affect
>   tbl_login_time at all.

You can't accomplish that with a foreign key constraint.

In some applications, ON DELETE SET NULL makes sense. But your application is essentially a log file stored in a SQL database. You have a significant problem in that you want to delete identifying information (users), but retain their ID numbers in some cases. I frankly don't understand why you're willing to retain the fact that user 23332 logged in at 18:40 today, while not caring whether you can identify who user 23332 *is*.

You have a few options.

- Drop the logfile table, and store logfile data in a file in the filesystem, not in the database. If I were in your shoes, I'd consider this first. If we're talking about a database that's somehow accessible over the web, make sure the log file is stored outside the web root. (I'd store it under /var/log with all the other log files.)
- Use foreign key constraints, and never delete a user.
- Use foreign key constraints, and live with the effect of ON DELETE SET NULL or ON DELETE SET DEFAULT. In this particular application ON DELETE SET NULL and ON DELETE SET DEFAULT are semantically equivalent. Both replace good data with data that doesn't identify the user. If you can't identify user 23332 anyway, who cares whether you know she logged in at 18:40 today?
- Drop the foreign key constraints, and use triggers to do whatever you like.

I'm pretty sure we agree that the most obvious option--use foreign keys with ON DELETE CASCADE--is simply wrong for your application.

Comment: `You can't accomplish that with a foreign key constraint.` - got it.  And you've convinced me you're right, what I'm trying to do doesn't make sense.  I was starting to lean that way and that's what prompted my question, but this was great feedback/advice, thanks.

Comment: Imagine like a Billing table, that holds records for all financials. And it has two references: 1) to a user, who changed ballance; 2). to the client account;

I'd like to keep all those records, even if I delete manager's user account or a client account. And using logfile is not an option here…

Comment: @pilat: Refine your requirements. In English, the requirement to "delete rows and yet keep all rows" is literally nonsense. (English is not your first language, right?) If you don't *really* want to delete rows, then you need a way to mark them as inactive, or mark them as "deleted" (without actually deleting them), or archive them, etc.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' refining: I want to retain the Billing records, even if the `user_id` (link to a manager who created the invoice) or the `client_id` is not longer exists in the referenced table.

Because it's money trail, we're keeping in the "Billing" table and it should stay. `SET NULL` is one of the options, but with IDs remaining I'll be able to at least see what was the same user/client and what's not. But, maybe, I should indeed take a path with `SET NULL` + some denormalization (like, writing user/client names directly to the Billing)

Comment: @pilat: For a money trail, you have to consider what might happen if you're taken to court. (USA-centric comment and caveats.) If you're taken to court, the bill you print today to submit as evidence must be essentially identical to the one you mailed 5 years ago. Write user/client (and product?) names to the Billing.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' it's not about court (though, it might  be and thank you for the advice), but I'm using the entire billing history to calculate current tenant's balance. This is the primary reason I can't remove billing records when some of "owners" is deleted.